# Function to concatenate type and string

Tags: c#, winforms, concatenation

My app saves and retrieves data from a file "x.ini". This file has a pattern of annual values. So in a normal year, it has 8760 values (one for each hour) and in a leap year has 8784 values.

```
xini file

[csv]
csv_001_01=value
csv_001_02=value
csv_001_03=value
.
csv_365_24=value
```

So, one by one the system loads with a giant code. We used a loop for to shorten the code.

But I don't know what the correct syntax to concatenate type and string on C#.

```
for(int d=1;d<=365;d++) //I'll put the code to not leap years.
{
    for(int h=1; h<=24; h++)
    {
        sMntHour[d,h] =
            Settings.csv["csv_" + d.ToString("000") + "_" + h.ToString("00")];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your concatenation operators should work. Another approach would be to use [`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d(v=vs.110).aspx), like this:

```
Settings.csv[string.Format("csv_{0:000}_{1:00}", d, h)];
```

This approach gives you slightly more readability, because the format string resembles the string that your code needs to produce, without concatenation operators in between its parts.

Comment: 'Monitor.Settings.csv' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context  -  Why?

Comment: if(File.Exists(ConfigINI))
                {
                IniFile ini=new IniFile(ConfigINI);

Comment: if(File.Exists(ConfigINI))
                {
                IniFile ini=new IniFile(ConfigINI); csv.csv_001_01=ini.ReadValue("csv","csv_001_01",csv.csv_001_01.ToString());

Comment: In the class Settings.cs has this Method

 public static void Read()
  {
  if(File.Exists(ConfigINI))
                {
                IniFile ini=new IniFile(ConfigINI); 
    csv.csv_001_01=ini.ReadValue("csv","csv_001_01",csv.csv_001_01.ToString());

Comment: I'm using VS2010 Ultimate.

Comment: Sorry please, Windows API on W7 64!

Comment: @OcaccyPontes The `IniFile` class looks like a class from [ini file reader from Code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1966/An-INI-file-handling-class-using-C) Is that the code that you are using? If `csv_001_01` and so on are fields on `csv`, setting them in a loop would be a little tricky, though. It can be done through reflection, but a better approach would be storing the settings in an associative container, such as a `Dictionary`.

Comment: Yes, being equal to the link! Can teach me about reflection or Dictionary with an example or link?

Comment: Thank you @dasblinkenlight, We fix it. Put in the same class the variables, array and method with for loop. 
    sMntHour[d,h] = string.Format("csv_{0:000}_{1:00}", d, h);